# FileZilla - небезопасное подключение

Tags: filezilla

При подключении к серверу, FileZilla выдает сообщение: "Небезопасный сервер, не поддерживает FTP через TLS.
Если продолжить, то ваши пароли и файлы будут передаваться открыто."

Вопрос: Это плохо? И какие пароли и файлы? Безопасно ли для компьютера в целом подобное подключение?

Comment: Нет, FTP без TLS передает все ваши данные (включая пароли) в незашифрованном виде. Выводы делайте сами.

Comment: @void можно уточнить какие пароли, есть угроза для моих файлов, которые не касаются тех что я загружу на сервер?  Я раньше не использовал програмку, поэтому озадачился

Comment: То, что вы передаёте по сети, может быть просмотрено посторонними лицами, находящимися на пути передачи данных (например, вашим интернет-провайдером). Того, чего вы не передаёте по сети, это никак не касается

Comment: Ну у вас же есть имя пользователя и пароль? Так вот, при соединении, эта программа пошлет эти данные для входа открытым методом. Товарищ майор может эти имя пользователя и пароль перехватить, даже не встав со стула.

Comment: @void понял, спасибо. Я просто думал что оно может работать как  вирус-стиллер, далек от этой темы вообщем

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо за ответ!